# How to extract text from Relative Layout and store it in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-layout, arraylist, android-uiautomator

I was trying to write a UiAutomator test for an application.
Here I have a bunch of textviews inside relative layouts from which I want to extract text and store it in a ArrayList. So that I can compare that ArrayList to the expected result list.

Any Suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Text from Relative Layout? Edittexts or TextViews?

Comment: how can you write text on `RelativeLayout`??

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that its TextViews

Comment: textviewobject.getText().toString() should do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over all children of a RelativeLayout and get its text.

```
for(int i=0; i< relLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) relLayout.getChildAt(i);
    String text = textView.getText().toString(); //put text in an ArrayList<String> as per your need
}
```

Hope this helps you.